# System freezes completely

Tags: nvidia, freeze, 19.10

Ubuntu 19.10 with all updates up to date. Today froze 2 times already (never happens in the previous year of using ubuntu 18.10, 19.04, 19.10).

A laptop with the screen closed, 1 external monitor plugged in via HDMI. NVidia + Intel GPUs. Wireless mouse + keyboard.

After the freeze both wireless and laptop controls do not respond. The only work-around is to press the power button.

The only possible meaningful message in `syslog`:

> /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5915]: (II) event4  - Telink Wireless Receiver Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.

Some possible helper links found:
- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/desktop-gnome-frequently-get-frozen-few-seconds-and-works-again/81603/20

---

Any clues how to diagnose this?

Comment: Suggest plugging in wired mouse and keyboard (or opening ssh terminal from mobile phone or another PC on the network). You can then hopefully debug the failed wireless device while it is happening, without reboot... eg. check dmesg for additional debug. If failure takes out all USB, then try ssh approach.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem and I suspect the SYN_DROPPED event may be a symptom of starvation from the system locking up and not indicative of the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the solution would be to go to the previous kernel version and wait for the new kernel to get released.

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue and for me, it looks like it is an nvidia issue:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1060783/linux/random-xid-61-and-xorg-lock-up

Check your syslog / kern.log for something like the following:

```
    [28736.200395] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:07:00: GPU-06a0a514-1651-491d-717c-2e1e24b93c99
    [28736.200398] NVRM: GPU Board Serial Number: 
    [28736.200399] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:07:00): 61, 0cb5(2d50) 00000000 00000000
```